# SAS Macro Variable Resolution

Tags: function, date, sas

I'm curious as to why some functions cannot interpret the character type of a macro variable correctly.

Here's a sample program

```
%let yymm = 1905;

data tst; 
reportDate = input(&yymm.,yymmn4.); 
run;
```

will produce a numeric value, reportDate, with a null associated with it.

But either of the following programs:

```
data tst;
reportDate = input("&yymm.",yymmn4.);
run;

data tst;
reportDate = input(put(&yymm.,4.),yymmn4.);
run;
```

will result in the correct value, 21670.

Since macro variables always resolve as characters, why can't the input function resolve the macro variable reference correctly? The first argument requires a character value, which the resolved reference &yymm. is. I've always been curious about this functionality.

Comment: Macro variables resolve as 'text' is a better way to think of it, and that text needs to be valid SAS code, which the above was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the macro processor has finished doing its magic the generated SAS code is then acted on by SAS itself.

The reason that code like:

```
reportDate = input(1905,yymmn4.);
```

results in a missing value is explained by the NOTE that SAS writes to the LOG.

```
478   data tst;
479   reportDate = input(1905,yymmn4.);
480   run;

NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
      479:20
```

Because you used a number instead of character string for the first argument in the INPUT() function SAS converted it to a character string for you.  When it does that it used the `BEST12.` format so you ended up with the string `'        1905'`
which starts with 8 blanks. Since you use a width of only 4 characters on your informat the result is a missing value.  The last 8 characters of converted string is ignored.

The other two versions fix this by giving INPUT() a string value instead. Either by generating an actual string literal or using the PUT() function to convert the number to a string using a format that does not produce the leading spaces.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Quote around the variable.

```
%let yymm = 1905;

data tst; 
reportDate = input("&yymm.",yymmn4.); 
run;
```

without quotes it's attempting to do this:

```
 data tst; 
    reportDate = input(1905,yymmn4.); 
 run;
```